Helm mount a set of confimaps or secrets dynamically
I have a use case for a helm deployment to mount a set of configmaps (it can be also secrets) which are present in the system already.
The configmaps follow a pattern *-version. As the name suggests, this contains version details of each application we have in the namespace. With this new deployment mounting all these configmaps, I can run a Prometheus exporter in there to scrape this information and send it to Prometheus.
I'm not sure if Helm can do this dynamically with a given pattern and loop somehow to form all the configmap mount to different files in the pod.
Optionally, I can define this configmap names in the values.yaml and also loop through it, but it would be bit difficult to maintain and to update values when there is new deployment added.

Can you show us a sample .values.yaml file and the expected result?

Can make a expected result, but as I stated in the question - what I was looking forward to was for Helm to somehow loop through a set of existing resources in the namespace(configmaps in this case). But I'm not sure if Helm can do that.
I have like 40+ configmaps with the name following <app_name>-version and the value is just the version number.
My intention is: All these configmaps to be mounted or read into the environment variables.

Helm is not supposed to read existing resources from Kubernetes, AFAIK. But you can use a script where you run one or more kubectl commands to generate a .values.yamlfile on the fly and then run Helm.

Thought about the exact same thing right now. I'm already testing some Kubectl commands to populate the values file.
Yes, I guess I'm looking at a functionality in the wrong tool, as Helm is not intended for working with existing resources may be

Maybe use the script not as part of a pipeline but only in your local machine, and run it once in a while to regenerate the values file? Then in your pipeline you just deploy the Helm chart. Be careful with solutions that are too dynamic, they can become a maintenance nightmare in a few months (or years) if not managed properly.

In principle you can use the Helm lookup function for this.  It might look something like
{{- $lookups := lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace "" }}
volumes:
{{- range $lookups.items }}
{{- if hasSuffix "-version" .metadata.name }}
  - name: {{ .metadata.name }}
    configMap:
      name: {{ .metadata.name }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
containers:
  - ...
    volumeMounts:
{{- range $lookups.items }}
{{- if hasSuffix "-version" .metadata.name }}
      - name: {{ .metadata.name }}
        mountPath: /tmp/{{ .metadata.name }}
        subPath: version
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

Note that this will not automatically update itself; you will need to helm upgrade the chart whenever the set of resources in the cluster changes.  Its behavior also depends heavily on what's in the cluster, which can make this hard to test.  But this is the only way to do this using only Helm.

In practice this seems like a good match for a custom controller or operator.  You can write code that calls the Kubernetes API to watch ConfigMaps, and regenerate the Deployment or other resources when the list of interesting ConfigMaps changes.

Didn't know about the lookup! Thanks for sharing.

Looks very solid. Thanks for sharing, I accepted the answer. Will come back to you after some testing

Updated your @DavidMaze answer with volume and volumeMount together to achieve what I wanted - mount all the configMaps to a folder under different files
